# Find the bytes that are most often found in the file

Tags: java, arrays, inputstream, fileinputstream

so basically i have C:/180301.txt file in which i have 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 numbers\bytes and output(49) is correct i think. my qustion is how to print out all elements which coming repetiteve times, now i have only one its 49

```
    private static ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        FileInputStream fileReader = new FileInputStream(br.readLine());
        while (fileReader .available() > 0)
        {
            list1.add(fileReader .read());
        }
        int element = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++)
        {
            if (same_element(list1.get(i)))
            {
                for (int j = 0; i < list1.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (list1.get(i).equals(list1.get(j)))
                    {
                        count++;
                        element = list1.get(j);
                        list2.add(list1.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (count > 1)
            System.out.println(element);
        fileReader.close();
    }
    private static boolean same_element(int list_i) {
        for (Integer aList2 : list2) if (list_i == aList2) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In same_element you have to switched true and false. 49 is prtinted because you never increase j. So the inner loop is buggy, too. But it should be deleted anyway because same_element now should do that job. The third problem is that you add the recent value only to the list of already seen value if it's already in there. That can't ever happen. So with some slight reworks your code might look like this:

```
List<Integer> fromFile = new ArrayList<>();
InputStream fileReader = new ByteArrayInputStream("71123456".getBytes("utf-8"), 0, 8);
while (fileReader.available() > 0) 
{
  fromFile.add(fileReader.read());
}
int element = 0;
int count = 0;
List<Integer> seen = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < fromFile.size(); i++) 
{
  Integer recent = fromFile.get(i);
  if (seen.contains(recent)) 
  {
    count++;
    element = recent;
  }
  seen.add(recent);
}
if (count > 1) System.out.println(element);
fileReader.close();
```

This prints the last duplicate, but still not the byte with most occurences. Today we write it like this:

```
Map<Byte, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(args[0]);

// build a map with byte value as a key refering to a counter in the value
for (Byte b: Files.readAllBytes(path)) {
  Integer old = counters.get(b);
  counters.put(b, (old == null ? 1 : old + 1));
}

// create a comparator that orders Map.Entry objects by their value. I.E. the 
// occurences of the respective byte. The order is ascending.
Comparator<Entry<Byte, Integer>> byVal = Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue());

// create a stream of Map.Entry objects. The stream is a new concept of Java8. 
// That's somehow like a collection, but more powerful. While the collection
// stores data he stream has a focus on manipulating
counters.entrySet().stream()
      // Use the comaparator in reversed form. That means the number of
      // occurences is now descending
      .sorted(byVal.reversed())
      // only use the first Map.Entry. I.E. the one with most occurences
      // a similar functionality is by filter. 
      // .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1) would use all duplicates
      .limit(1)
      // print out the results. Of course the argument for println can be 
      // concatenated from several parts like: 
      // e.getKey() +  "\tcount: " + e.getValue()
      .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey()));
```

Java 8 helps a lot for problems like this. Tying to write the same with former versions take quite a bit more code.

Comment: ok but its still printiong out only one element which come most often, but what i want is if i have like 51 51 51 52 52 52 53 54 55 56, to print out 51 and 52, how can i do this?

Comment: @Predict_it I left some more comments. Just play around a bit and look up the concepts like Comparator and Stream. The principle is very flexible and I think you can get into it pretty quickly.